# Как сделать чтобы блок footer не опускался за границы родительского контейнера

Tags: css, css3

Всем доброго времени суток. Нужен совет.
Есть 3 блока: `.header`, `.content`, `.footer` помещенные в `.container` (aqua):

```html
<div class="container" style="background: aqua">
  <div class="header"> This is header. . . </div>
  <div class="content">
    1<br>
    2<br>
    3
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> This is footer </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо чтобы при увеличении высоты `.content` элемент `.footer` опускался до тех пор пока не дойдет до нижней границы `.container`. Дальнейшее добавление контента в `.content` не должно приводить к увеличению высоты, а только к появлению скрола (`overflow-y: auto`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого-то есть идеи как это можно сделать средствами CSS?

**P.S. ВАЖНО!** Высота `.header` не известна и вычисляется самим браузером на основании содержимого. Высоту `.footer` мы можем условно принять в 30 px если это поможет решить задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать вертикальный `flex`, отключив сжатие у `.header` и `.footer`

```css
.container{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 160px;
}
.header{
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.content{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.footer{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background: aqua">
  <div class="header"> This is header. . . </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> This is footer </div>
</div>
```

Comment: работает как надо когда данные не помещаются в `.content`, но когда данных мало, то `.footer` не прижимается к `.content`  (рис. 1), а остается внизу контейнера

Comment: Если нужно такое поведение при фиксированной высоте `.content`, то ему нужно задать `flex: 0 1 auto`

Comment: благодарю, работает

Answer (score 2):

Подходит ли вам данный вариант с использованием гридов?

```css
.container
{
  background-color: aqua;
  
  height: 100px;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-content: start;
}

.content
{
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header,
.content,
.footer
{
  border: 1px solid #ACACAC;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">This is header</div>
    <div class="content">
    Line 01<br>
    Line 02<br>
    Line 03<br>
    Line 04<br>
    Line 05<br>
    Line 06<br>
    Line 07<br>
    Line 08<br>
    Line 09<br>
    Line 10<br>
    Line 11<br>
    Line 12<br>
    Line 13<br>
    Line 14
  </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">
    Line 1<br>
    Line 2
  </div>
    <div class="footer">This is footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Гриды использовать можно, но результат такой же как и при использовании вертикального flex: когда данных мало, то футер не прижимается к `.content` как показано на картинке 1, а вместо этого он всегда прижат к низу контейнера

Comment: На самом то деле я понимал, что задача не растягивать контент на всю доступную высоту. Пытался бороться с этим, но пока еще не понял как. Надеялся, что такой вариант вам понравится больше хех.

Comment: Отредактировал. Теперь работает как у вас.

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаем контейнеру высоту экрана и делаем его флекс блоком, шапке и футеру устанавливаем flex-shrink: 0; чтобы занимали столько места сколько им надо, а контент overflow-y: auto

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.header,
.footer {
flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
overflow-y: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background: aqua">
  <div class="header"> This is header. . . </div>
  <div class="content">
    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3    1<br>
    2<br>
    3
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> This is footer </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.header,
.footer {
flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
overflow-y: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background: aqua">
  <div class="header"> This is header. . . </div>
  <div class="content">
    1<br>
    2<br>
    3
  </div>
  <div class="footer"> This is footer </div>
</div>
```